# How to launch an aplay interactive process using systemd without interaction

Tags: systemd, alsa

**Context:**

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero with an Adafruit Speaker Bonnet sound card on it.
Skipping all the details, it's known that this add on has "pop" issues when starting to play a new sound. It's related to an i2s clocking problem etc..

There are threads all around the web about that specific issue but only two solutions exists:

- Modify the hardware to use a dedicated pin for powering on and off the IC between plays.
- Keep the audio open all the time and never close it.

I try to implement the second option.

One way to do it ( in a CLI environment ) is to run:

```
/usr/bin/aplay -t raw -r 48000 -c 2 -f S32_LE /dev/zero
```

And never quit that aplay instance. But one drawback is the additional load on the CPU... because a play is really processing all the 0 from /dev/zero and play them.

Another, more clever, way of keeping the audio open is to call aplay in interactive mode:

```
aplay -i
```

It opens the audio stream and still waste a little CPU but not as many as before.

It's still a workaround but it seems to do what I need.

**Question**

How do I start the command `aplay -i` at boot in a transparent manner ?

My Pi uses systemd.

I tried to create a service ( /etc/systemd/system/aplay.service) with :

```
[Unit]
Description=Invoke aplay from at system start to avoid pops.

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/aplay -Ddmixer -i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but I got the following result:

```
aplay.service - Invoke aplay from at system start to avoid pops.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/aplay.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-11-01 11:58:16 CET; 1h 30min ago
  Process: 613 ExecStart=/usr/bin/aplay -Ddmixer -i (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 613 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 01 11:58:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Invoke aplay from /dev/zero at system start..
Nov 01 11:58:16 raspberrypi aplay[613]: aplay: read_header:2834: read error
Nov 01 11:58:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: aplay.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 01 11:58:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: aplay.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Additional info**

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63+ #1459 Wed Oct 6 16:40:27 BST 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I use PI OS Lite 32Bit in a headless environment.
No desktop environment installed.

My alsa config:

/etc/asound.conf

```
pcm.speakerbonnet {
   type hw card 0
}

pcm.!default {
   type plug
   slave.pcm "dmixer"
}

pcm.dmixer {
   type dmix
   ipc_key 1024
   ipc_perm 0666
   slave {
     pcm "speakerbonnet"
     period_time 0
     period_size 1024
     buffer_size 8192
     rate 44100
     channels 2
   }
}

ctl.dmixer {
  type hw card 0
}
```

~/.asoundrc:

```
pcm.speakerbonnet {
   type hw card 0
}

pcm.dmixer {
   type dmix
   ipc_key 1024
   ipc_perm 0666
   slave {
     pcm "speakerbonnet"
     period_time 0
     period_size 1024
     buffer_size 8192
     rate 44100
     channels 2
   }
}

ctl.dmixer {
    type hw card 0
}

pcm.softvol {
    type softvol
    slave.pcm "dmixer"
    control.name "PCM"
    control.card 0
}

ctl.softvol {
    type hw card 0
}

pcm.!default {
    type             plug
    slave.pcm       "softvol"
}
```